# Company A has 40% of German cars and company B has 10% of German cars. All other cars are Korean.Help needed solving Bayesian Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**There are 2 taxi companies. Company A has 40% of German cars and company B has 10% of German cars. All other cars are Korean. Taxi aggregator assigns orders to A or B with probabilities 1/3 and 2/3 respectively. If German car arrives, what's the probability that it's from company B?**

So my solution for this problem would be using Bayes Theorem

According to me the question is asking to find P(car being from company B|Being German)
So using Bayes theorem it would be equal to

$P(B|G)=(P(B) * P(G|B))/P(G)$  and that would be

$P(B|G)=((2/3)*0.1)/0.25= 4/15$ which is wrong. I would like to know where am i making mistake

Here P(B) is probability of car being from company B
P(G) is probability of car being German

I found P(G) considering there are 100 cars in  both company A and B so $50/200=1/4=0.25$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: done sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law of total probability:

$P(G) = P(G|A)P(A) + P(G|B) P(B) = 0.4*1/3 + 0.1*2/3 = 0.2$.

By the way, the cars should be Mercedes Benz please.

Comment: Thank you i got the answer as 1/3 which is right

Answer (score -1):

$P(B|G)=(P(G|B)*P(B))/P(G)$

$P(G|B)=0.1$
$P(B)=2/3$
$P(G)=P(G|A)*P(A)+P(G|B)*P(B)=0.4*(1/3)+0.1*(2/3)$

The answer should be $P(B|G)=1/3$.